# Ошибка с переменной типа Array

Tags: java, компиляция

В результате компиляции программы выдало ошибку

```
/partrain/src/ParallelTraining.java:309: error: cannot find symbol
                            Array array = contonewdatabase.createArrayOf("string", residualgroupparam);
                            ^
  symbol:   class Array
  location: class Reduce
```

Я подозреваю, что не подключил необходимую библиотеку. Подскажите, что надо подключить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.sql.Array
```